# Как загрузить ВСЕ ресурсы из конкретного xml-файла не задавая ни имени ни значения

Tags: java, android, android-resources

Как (и можно ли вообще) загрузить ВСЕ ресурсы из конкретного xml-файла не задавая ни имени, ни значения.
Например есть names.xml с кодом:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="name1">Ab</string>
  <string name="name2">Ac</string>
  <string name="name3">Ad</string>
</resources>
```

Оттуда надо получить массивы:

```java
arrNames = { "name1", "name2", "name3" };
arrVal = { "Ab", "Ac", "Ad" };
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как найти ресурс по имени в конкретном ресурсном файле](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617609/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5)

Answer (score 3):

Загрузить ресурсы из определенного xml-файла не получится. Но есть способ получить все ресурсы из всех string-директорий.

Добавьте `import java.lang.reflect.*;`

```
Field[] fields = R.string.getFields();
String[] arrNames = new String[fields.length];
String[] arrVal = new String[fields.length];

for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    arrNames[i] = fields[i].getName();
    arrVal[i] = (String) fields[i].get(R.string);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Но мне нужны строки из конкретного файла names.xml? А ваш код не приведет к загрузке вообще всех строк из всех файлов?

Comment: Или в полученном массиве надо потом искать нужные данные? Вообще у меня складывается впечатление, что имена произвольных файлов в папке values для java ничего не означают :(

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String Вы правы, что имена произвольных файлов со строками в папке values ничего не значат, все их идентификаторы будут храниться в R.string. Наверно, придётся искать нужные данные вм самим.

Comment: Вроде бы нужный мне вариант можно получить создав массив строк со ссылками на нужные строки <item>@string/name1</item>. Имена брать из массива, а значения искать в строках. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: @Imihael, Вас понял. Когда в следующий раз будете задавать вопрос, спрашивайте, пожалуйста, о конкретной проблеме, которую действительно нужно решить, а не о вашем [неправильном] способе решить проблему (получить все строки без значений и имён). Это даст вам верное решение действительной проблемы.

Comment: :) когда понимаешь как правильно спросить, то уже сам знаешь ответ.