# Как найти ресурс по имени в конкретном ресурсном файле

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, уважаемые знатоки. 
Подскажите пожалуйста как найти ресурс по имени в конкретном ресурсном файле.
Например есть names.xml с кодом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="name1">Ab</string>
  <string name="name2">Ac</string>
  <string name="name3">Ad</string>
</resources>
```

Надо найти значение name2:

```
myName="name2";
```

Я знаю как найти это во всех ресурсных файлах, но мне нужно в конкретном names.xml:

```
int settId = getResources().getIdentifier("name2", "string", getPackageName());
myName = getString(settId);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без каких-то дополнительных действий - никак. Система сборки объединяет все ресурсы в один файл, имена исходных файлов теряются. Используйте префикс для этой группы ресурсов, либо создайте список в коде или в ресурсе с помощью `<string-array>`

Comment: Да спасибо. Уже понял.